# Maven structure with a single exposed artifact and internal dependencies

Tags: maven, dependency-management, maven-release-plugin

I'm currently building an application and I have a maven project structured like so:

```
|-> root
|
|-------> ui
|       |---> pom.xml
|
|-------> core
|       |---> pom.xml
|
|
|-------> pom.xml
```

- **ui** depends on **core**
- **core** has no internal dependencies
- `root/pom.xml` is an aggregator which specifies as it's modules `ui` and `core`

Now I'm planning to `mvn release` this piece of software and I only want to expose a central artifact say `myapp` which should be a jar containing all the code from `ui` and `core` (ie. I don't want ui, core, and the aggregator to all be released separately) so that anyone who adds `myapp` as a dependency can access both `com.somepackage.ui` as well as `com.somepackage.core`.

Questions:

- How do I handle the `ui -> core` dependency? Can I make it point to a relative pom `../core/pom.xml`?
- How do I bundle the generated sources from `ui` and `core` into a `${rootartifactname}.jar`
- Running `mvn deploy` on `root` deploys all three poms to the repository, so right now anyone can reference my `ui` artifact and I don't want that, how do I expose only the root pom artifact

Comment: I think it's not trivial. The easiest way to achieve all goals is to have only a single Maven project and rely on packages for structuring.

Comment: "How do I handle the ui -> core dependency? Can I make it point to a relative pom../core/pom.xml?" You can use a regular dependency.

Comment: "How do I bundle the generated sources from uiand core into a ${rootartifactname}.jar" The maven-assembly-plugin can bundle Jars in a Zip file. This might be an alternative option. And there is an izpack-plugin for creating installers.

Comment: The maven-dependency-plugin could be used for extracting files from Jars for packaging in a common Jar.

Comment: Creating the final artifact can be done in a separate Maven project next to ui and core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create another module, `myapp`, that will specifically package your application including `ui` and `core`. This new module will depend on both the `ui` and `core` modules, and Maven will take care of the build order itself. Then, you can configure your build only to deploy / release the `myapp` module.

Although it isn't something would generally be recommended, [it is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296170/how-to-skip-the-release-or-specific-modules-in-the-maven-repo) to configure certain modules of a multi-module Maven project to not be released by the [`maven-release-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/). For that, you need to tell the [`maven-deploy-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/) to skip its default execution.

A simple implementation of the `myapp` module would be the following:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>my.groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>root</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>my.groupId</groupId>
      <artifactId>ui</artifactId> <!-- brings core transitively -->
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <skip>false</skip>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Then, in the parent module, called `root`, you would have a default

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <skip>true</skip>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When you run `mvn clean deploy` or when you perform a release with the Release Plugin, only the module configured to be deployed will actually be deployed or released. In this case, it would only be the `myapp` module: `ui`, `core` and even the parent POM, won't be deployed.

For your real use-case, `myapp` could create an uber jar, but this sketch is enough to show that it is possible.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I have tried to do what you described and deployed the `myapp` jar to the repository but users can't use because it references a parent and the parent is not uploaded. Then probably parent will not be able to be used because `ui` and `core` won't be there either. Any way around this?

Comment: @ᴘᴀɴᴀʏɪᴏᴛɪs Well I thought you only wanted to deploy `myapp` so that users would download just that. You'd need the parent if you're going to have a dependency on it, yes, in which case you can skip the deployment of `ui` and `core`, and not the parent. It shouldn't cause trouble with the two modules not being deployed.

Comment: Yes I only wanted to deploy `myapp` and on your sample pom you added a `<parent>` tag which I thought was needed, I removed it and republished `myapp` and everything works great, thanks again!